# Some code shows as picture in php with Imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, content-type, imagick

I use imagemagick to show picture in php by this code:

```
$img=new Imagick('C:/xampp/htdocs/img/core.png');
echo $img;
```

Instead of showing picture I see some code in browser like this:

> w�zƿ�sr3���������)I0�C���۱�

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the browser you issuing and image first and add the appropriate headers:

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

Comment: thanks for you answeer, when i add this code header('Content-type: image/png'); a broken picture shown in browser

Comment: $img=new Imagick('C:/xampp/htdocs/DealWordsFirstVersion/img/core.png');
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $img;

Comment: above code is all the code I just want too show a picture

Comment: at the top add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`